# PHP Opencart - Edit Orders

Tags: php, opencart

Goodmorning Stacks,

Since a couple of days we've been working on a dropshipping-service inside an existing webshop (opencart 1.5.6). I already prepared my SOAP-request (dropshipping) for use inside the store, the only thing I'm not sure about is the location of the desired method. Since you've need to complete the payment before you can confirm the order it seems we need to adjust the

```
catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php
```

However when I look up the code of this file I can't find any clue where to place the method.
Inside the `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` we can find the addOrder() method, looks like this is a temp order till you've succesfully completed your payment and pressed the confirm button.

Can anybody tell me about the way Opencart handles the orders and how-to adjust the code the proper way at the right location?

Comment: What exactly do You need to achieve? At which exact point You need to call that soap service?

Comment: We got six steps, in step 5 you've got too select the payment option.  After step 6 you'll have to complete your payment before you can selec t the order confirmation button. I need to call the SOAP request right after that confirmation.

Comment: In this case You can add Your SOAP callback into `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php` **before** all the order data stored in session is `unset` so that You can still access them. After Your callback is done the session variables are unset and the checkout success messages are displayed as usual.

Comment: Great, will give it a try :)! In the previous situation I placed my method at the end of step 5 but that was a pretty big mistake.

Comment: This seems the fix I need! However I just need to pass some data from step 5 to step 6 (product data, sku, etc). Do you have a tutorial how to accomplish this? Or perhaps a little advice?

Comment: On that place where You are calling Your SOAP callback You can access the products that were ordered - get their IDs and load details for each product by it's ID. Nothing complicated...

Comment: I got it working! Just called the order model and made a line too the getOrder() method for receiving the data I need. SOAP Request working now :)! Thanks for the help bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having just done this myself, whilst I'm aware this question is from a while ago I thought it would be helpful to post my approach.

The method I have used is to execute a function in a separate file, and call this from `catalog/controller/checkout/success.php`

There are two methods to do this, either via directly updating the file or by using vQmod. I'm not going to go into much detail on vQmod here as it is covered extensively elsewhere (https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/).
The latter is my preference as it requires no modification of the original file, however I will be covering both.

1) To modify the file directly, simply open it and on line 7 you will see

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
```

immediately after this line you can add your hook. I used something like

```
include("catalog/controller/checkout/dropship_order.php");
sendOrderToDropship($this->session->data);
```

2) Alternatively, use the following vQmod code to perform the same action on the fly

```
<file name="catalog/controller/checkout/success.php" error="log">
    <operation error="skip">
    <search position="after"><![CDATA[if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[
            include("catalog/controller/checkout/dropship_order.php");
            sendOrderToDropship($this->session->data);
    ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```

Both of these methods will result in the calling of your `sendOrderToDropship` function when the success page is loaded; and inside that function you can perform whatever action you require. By sending in the `data` array, you also gain access to the order information (critically the order id) so you can perform any processing required.

Hope that helps!